# How to define props for react-navigation with Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, flowtype

I am working on a simple React Native App, and have decided to user react-navigation.  I have also decided to go with Flow for static type checking.  What I can't figure out, is how to define navigation related props with Flow.

e.g. I define my App.js to use StackNavigator like so:

```
import StackNavigator from 'react-navigation';
import Main from './app/containers/Main';

const App = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Main },
});

export default App;
```

then I define my Main class, but I don't know how to reference react-navigation in my props:

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
  navigate: ????
};

type State = {};

class Main extends Component<Props, State> {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

According to https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3643

```
import { NavigationState, NavigationScreenProp } from 'react-navigation';

type Props = {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState>
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Import `NavigationScreenProp` from `react-navigation`:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationScreenProp } from 'react-navigation';

type Props = {
  navigate: NavigationScreenProp<{}>
};

type State = {};

class Main extends Component<Props, State> {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`react-navigation` has a flow file. Maybe you can import from there or just copy-paste

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/flow/react-navigation.js#L72

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Cannot import the type NavigationState as a value. Use the import type instead.

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import type { NavigationState, NavigationScreenProp } from 'react-navigation';

type Props = {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState>
}
type State = {}


class Main extends Component<Props, State> {
   ...
}
```

You can also add below to .flowconfig to prevent flow-typed/npm/redux-devtools-extension_v2.x.x.js:23:33

```
[lints]
deprecated-utility=off
```